# svg linearGradient and set the color space interpolation

Tags: interpolation, linear-gradients, color-space

In svg, you can define [a linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient) that interpolates between two colors in space.

*Edit* The [docs indicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#LinearGradientElementSpreadMethodAttribute) some rgb spaces but not many. Are there any workarounds?

I'm wondering if anyone has been able to try different color interpolations for the gradients. It would great to be able to use perceptually uniform spaces for the linear transformation.

Comment: Well there is a [color-interpolation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#ColorInterpolationProperty) in the specs, but IIRC, no browser really supports it... (But they might support the [color-interpolation-filters](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#ColorInterpolationFiltersProperty) so maybe there would be a way going through filters, though I'm really not sure)

Comment: It is indeed possible through filters: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=298281#c3 and #c4 for correction. https://jsfiddle.net/eubahr4s/

Comment: I've come up with a way to simulate a solution in d3. @Kaiido

Comment: @Kaiido Firefox nightlies support it now. Will be part of version 123

Answer (score 2):

The specs do define a [*color-interpolation*](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#ColorInterpolationProperty) property, which values should be settable to `auto | sRGB | linearRGB | inherit`.
But currently only Firefox 123+ supports `linearRGB`, other browsers still default to `sRGB` value.  [chromium bug](https://issues.chromium.org/issues/324440102)

But it might be possible to workaround this issue through a `<filter>` correcting the gamma values.

Holger Will in [aforementioned bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=298281#c3) provided such a filter:

```html
<svg width="600" height="120" viewBox="0 0 600 120">

  <defs>
    <filter id="toLinearRGB" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="1"
  height="1">
      <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
         <feFuncR type="gamma" amplitude="1" exponent="0.454545454545" offset="0"/>
         <feFuncG type="gamma" amplitude="1" exponent="0.454545454545" offset="0"/>
         <feFuncB type="gamma" amplitude="1" exponent="0.454545454545" offset="0"/>
         <feFuncA type="gamma" amplitude="1" exponent="0.454545454545" offset="0"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="blue"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="red"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect width="600" height="120" fill="gray"/>
  <rect x="50" y="10" width="500" height="40" fill="url(#gradient)"/>
  <rect x="50" y="70" width="500" height="40" fill="url(#gradient)" filter="url(#toLinearRGB)"/>

</svg>

<p>Should look like</p>
<img src="http://tavmjong.free.fr/SVG/COLOR_INTERPOLATION/color_interpolation_gradient.png">

<br>
<code>base svg code and image from <a href="http://tavmjong.free.fr/SVG/COLOR_INTERPOLATION/#Gradients">http://tavmjong.free.fr/SVG/COLOR_INTERPOLATION/#Gradients</a></code><br>
<code>"toLinearRGB" filter from <a href="https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=298281#c3">https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=298281#c3</a></code>
```

Comment: Firefox now does support linearRGB from version 123 and Chrome plans to join us too.